# Is there a rule of thumb to decide when to use trigger or triggerMethod in Backbone.Marionette?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I'm playing a bit with `Backbone.js` and `Backbone.Marionette` and I would like to know what's the difference between `trigger` and `triggerMethod`.

In particular, is there any rule of thumb to decide when use the former or the latter?

In my mind events, for example, are useful to communicate between a DOM element and its view.

`triggerMethod` is used in Marionette to update in cascade different components, e.g. a layout calls the `show` method to its children (children respond to `onShow`). So, for me its the same as calling a direct method on it. Is this true?

What about `trigger`?

Thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There isn't a huge difference, and it simply depends on what you want to do...

- `trigger` will trigger an event
- `triggerMethod` will trigger an event *AND* call a corresponding method according to naming convention (see https://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.1.0/marionette.functions.html#marionettetriggermethod)

Obviously, if you only want to trigger an event, you'd use `trigger`. But using `trigger` you also create a "home made" triggerMethod implementation: `trigger` the event, then have a listener that will call the function you want.

So what about `triggerMethod` ? As mentioned above, it will trigger an event and call a method. So if your only objective is to call the method in the first place, there isn't necessarily a need for using `triggerMethod`.

So why would one use `triggerMethod` at all? Because it gives you "hooks" to add functionality with event listeners. In my [book on Marionette](https://leanpub.com/marionette-gentle-introduction/), for example, there is a `triggerMethod` call in https://github.com/davidsulc/marionette-gentle-introduction/blob/master/assets/js/apps/contacts/edit/edit_controller.js#L24 to display error messages on a form. The same could be achieved by simply calling

```
view.onFormDataInvalid(contact.validationError);
```

But as mentioned above, `triggerMethod` give us a "hook" for later use. For example, let's say I want to add logging of user errors: I can simply add a listener to my view:

```
initialize: function(){
  this.on("form:data:invalid", function(validationError){
    // log error here
  }
}
```

This additonal functionality can be added without impacting the rest of the code, because we've used `triggerMethod` instead of a direct method call. In addition, it will be easier to test later (small tests, with single point of failure):

- test that "form:data:invalid" event is triggered when a user enters incorrect info
- test that when "form:data:invalid" event is triggered, error gets logged
- etc.

Comment: Awesome. So I could just use `triggerMethod` instead of `trigger`. But in both cases the view will respond to them is the same of the one I send that message to. True? With an exception for collection views that are able to forward events. P.S. I've already your books. ;-)

Comment: Errata: ...the one I send the message from.

Comment: If you call `myView.triggerMethod("do:something", x)`, the `onDoSomething` method will be called on `myView`, and will receive argument `x`...

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the great explanation. But the link provided above [https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.functions.md#marionettetriggermethod] is not working.

Comment: Indeed the answer is 4.5 years old, and it seems Marionette has reworked its documentation. You can find the information you're after at https://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.1.0/marionette.functions.html#marionettetriggermethod (I've updated the link in the answer)

Answer (score 8):

#### `trigger(name)`

- Part of `Backbone.js`
- Triggers event using the name passed in

#### `triggerMethod(name)`

- Part of `Marionnete.js`
- Does everything `trigger(name)` does
- Also calls methods using a predefined naming convention.

  eg. `triggerMethod('foo')` will call `onFoo()`

  eg. `triggerMethod('foo:bar')` will call `onFooBar()`

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Here my question was: why prefer the latter to the former? Have you any other case different from David one?