# How a childView listens to another childView events correctly using marionettejs?

Tags: javascript, events, marionette

So, I have a layoutView, lets call it MyLayoutView. In this layout view I 
have two childViews:

```
return Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
    template: templates.pages.layoutTpl,
    regions: {
        regionTest1: "#test1-view",
        regionTest2: "#test2-view"
    },
    childEvents: {
        'my:event': function (childView, param) {
            console.log(param); //its ok
        }})
```

and in the childView(CompositeView), I trigger an event, like this:

```
this.triggerMethod('my:event', [1,2,3]);
```

works fine. How can I listen to this event from the other childView?

So far i do it in the LayoutView:

```
'my:event': function (childView, params) {
            this.getRegion('regionTest2').currentView.trigger('my:event2');
        },
```

and in regionTest2 I listen to the event:

```
//in the secord childView
this.on('my:event2', function() {//do whatever...})
```

to catch the event in the other childView. OK it works, but I think the writing is a little ugly.. any suggestions to it better?

Answer (score 0):

You're mostly on the right track if you want to use your parent layout view to mediate events between the child views(you can also use [triggerMethod](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.2/marionette.functions.html#marionettetriggermethod) [instead of triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21065336/5063583)).

However, the reason it feels ugly is because of the use of a parent layout view as a mediator to connect its seemingly disjoint child views. There are many approaches and messaging and eventing patterns to solve this, as well as few plugins like [Backbone.Radio](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.radio)(marionette is slated to replace wreqr with radio as dependency). If it is possible, I would suggest leveraging Backbone Radio's Channels to better namespace and manage your events(e.g. creating and managing channels based on their purpose), and also to help decouple your views.

Comment: Hi Akshad, thanks for your reply, i will try Backbone.Radio plugin soon.